# How do I inject a service into X that must be instantiated with X as an argument?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a business-type service, let's call it `AccountService`.

```
class AccountService : IAccountService {
    public AccountService(ILoggingService log) {
        _log = log;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this service requires a logging service in ctor injection.

The logging service must be instantiated passing the containing service as a type:

```
var log = LoggingServiceFactory.GetService(typeof(AccountService));
```

How do I define the object graph so the logging service gets injected as a new instance, passing account service as a type?

I could do this

```
container.RegisterType<IAccountService, AccountService>();
container.RegisterType<ILoggingService>( /* ??? */);
```

...but I'm not sure what to put in there.

Do I have to do this?

```
container.RegisterType<IAccountService>( () => return new AccountService(LoggingServiceFactory.GetService(typeof(AccountService)));
```

That is OK for this example, but what if my `AccountService` required other injections as well?  Do I have to put everything in that one lambda expression?

```
container.RegisterType<IAccountService>( () => return new AccountService(LoggingServiceFactory.GetService(typeof(AccountService)), container.Resolve<IOtherService>(), container.Resolve<ISecondOtherService>());
```

If I do that, what if the other services also require other services (including the logging service again)?  Seems like this could get pretty messy pretty fast.

I guess I change things so I could inject the factory instead:

```
class AccountService : IAccountService {
    public AccountService(LoggingServiceFactory factory) {
        _log = factory.GetService(typeof(this));
    }
}
```

and register them this way:

```
container.RegisterType<IAccountService, AccountService>();
container.RegisterType<LoggingServiceFactory, LoggingServiceFactory>();
```

...but alas there is no `ILoggingServiceFactory` so I will have to inject a concrete type, which makes it harder to unit test. I cannot change the logging service (it's third party and we have to use it).

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it in multiple ways:

1) Use factory to get logging service using the reflected class type:

```
class AccountService : IAccountService 
{
    public AccountService(ILoggingServiceFactory factory) 
    {
        _log = factory.GetService(this.GetType());
    }
}
```

2) Use factory generic method:

```
class AccountService : IAccountService 
{
    public AccountService(ILoggingServiceFactory factory) 
    {
        _log = factory.GetService<AccountService>();
    }
}
```

3) Make logging service generic

```
class AccountService : IAccountService 
{
    public AccountService(ILoggingService<AccountService> log) 
    {
        _log = log;
    }
}
```

Comment: As noted in my question, there is no `ILoggingServiceFactory`.

Comment: As noted in the second answer, I don't recommend you tightly couple your logging implementation to a particular logging library. I would create the ILoggingServiceFactory and ILoggingService which delegates logging to the current logging provider you are using.

Comment: Then you can configure during startup with something like
container.RegisterType<ILoggingServiceFactory, Log4NetLoggingServiceFactory>.

Comment: The logging library already abstracts the logging implementation from me... seems overkill to abstractify the abstraction just to define an interface for the factory.  If I wanted to change the library that contains the abstraction, I would change the composition root to point to a different abstraction.  Is that really the only way?

Comment: The idea is that you are limited to the functionality that is provided to you by your logging abstraction. Obviously the current abstraction does not support creating a logger scoped to the class that is being instantiated, thus you've already coupled yourself in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what IoC you are using, but most have a way to do this:

```
container.Register<LoggingService>();
```

Where you would just get a new instance of `LoggingService` wherever it was asked for. Most will also have ways to register singleton instances as well. Above is specifically the syntax SimpleInjector uses (it's just what I have sitting in front of me at the moment).

> I cannot change the logging service (it's third party and we have to
>   use it).

I would not use a concrete type unless I absolutely had no choice. Even though you cannot modify it, you can always wrap it in your own concrete class that you can then tie an interface to.

This would allow you to no longer be bound to the concrete class and easily swap the logging service out for another one.

Comment: Right, that much I get... but the new LoggingService must be instantiated with an argument of type `Type` that matches the code that is being logged (so that the logger can emit scope information).  How do I pass that  argument to the constructor? That is the question.

Comment: @JohnWu Oh... that is not normally injected through the constructor, but rather instantiated in the constructor. fbhdev is more correct in creating a factory.